# How to prevent that a draggable widget overflow it's parent in flutter

Tags: windows, flutter, sqlite, drag-and-drop, draggable

I'm trying to build a tool to create database models with flutter and I want that when I create a widget (that will be the representation of a table) it could be dragged just inside of it's parent, I don't want that the feedback overflow it's parent.

Here is the code that I have build:

```
class CreateTableTool extends StatefulWidget {
  const CreateTableTool({super.key});

  @override
  State<CreateTableTool> createState() => _CreateTableToolState();
}

class _CreateTableToolState extends State<CreateTableTool> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Draggable(
        feedback: Container(
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.red, width: 1)
          ),
        ),
        child: Container(
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.blue, width: 1)
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

This is the instance of the widget inside of the Dashboard statefull widget:

```
Widget MainControl = CreateTableTool();
```

Here is where the widget is placed:

```
Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    children: [
        Expanded(child: MainControl)
    ],
),
```

[image: Example]

Do you have some idea of how I could implement a camera zoom and movement only inside this widget as well?